# nginx... why do I need the additional location block?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I was wondering if you could clarify why adding what I did was able to fix my problem as although my problem is fixed, I'm not sure why it works and it wasn't working in the setup before.

**The old setup:**

I have files served at the following address:
`http://192.168.33.1:3000/bower_components/...`
e.g., (`http://192.168.33.1:3000/bower_components/animate.css/animate.css`)

I have an nginx reverse proxy set up at
http://192.168.33.10:80/

I have the following location block:

```
location /content {
   proxy_pass http://192.168.33.1:3000/;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
   client_max_body_size 10m;
   client_body_buffer_size 128k;
   proxy_connect_timeout 90;
   proxy_send_timeout 90;
   proxy_read_timeout 90;
   proxy_buffer_size 4k;
   proxy_buffers 4 32k;
   proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
   proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
}
```

In this setup, the following url would load:
`http://192.168.33.10/content/app/index.css`

but the following url would give me a 404, even though accessing the file directly would load just fine:
`http://192.168.33.10/content/bower_components/animate.css/animate.css`
(or anything else in the bower_components folder for that matter)

**The fix:**

After playing around a bit I found that if I added the following location block, things would work:

```
location /content/bower_components {
     proxy_pass http://192.168.33.1:3000/bower_components;
}
```

I understand why this additional location block would work but I don't understand why the original location block did not encompass the rule of the addition location block that I added.

Any advise as to what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the correct answer, but...

The location block:

```
location /content {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.33.1:3000/;
    ...
}
```

is aliasing URIs beginning with `/content` to `/`, which is missing a terminating `/`.

I would use:

```
location /content/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.33.1:3000/;
    ...
}
```

and then fix the specific case of `/content` if you need to.

I don't know why `http://192.168.33.10/content/app/index.css` seems to work though.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.